# Problema al mover un archivo

Tags: java

tengo un problema, quiero mover todos los archivos de una subcarpeta la la raiz, y en caso de que la carpeta raiz tenga un archivo con el mismo nombre, cambie el nombre del archivo a mover.
Ejemplo este es mi directorio
C:/raiz/Hola.txt
C:/raiz/Adiostxt
C:/raiz/subCarpeta1/Hola.txt
Lo que quiero hacer es mover el Hola.txt de subCarpeta1 a raiz, pero como en este caso, raiz ya contiene un Hola.txt, quiero cambiar de subCarpeta1/Hola.txt a subCarpeta1/Hola - Copia 1.txt y despues moverlo a raiz.
Tengo el siguiente código, pero en vez de cambiar el nombre del archivo en subCarpeta1, me lo cambia al de raiz.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Moviator {
public static void move(File origen, File destino) throws IOException {
    if(destino.exists()) 
        destino.renameTo(new  File(getValidName(destino.getAbsolutePath())));


    if(origen.exists()) { 

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(origen);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destino);

        int len;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while( (len = is.read(buffer)) > 0 ) os.write(buffer, 0, len);

        is.close();
        os.close();
        origen.delete();
    }

}


private static String getValidName(String path) {
    int i = 1;
    String[] aux = getData(path);
    String newName = aux[0]+" - Copia "+(i++)+aux[1];

    File newFile = new File(newName);

    if(newFile.exists())
        newName = getValidName(path);

    return newName;
}

private static String[] getData(String filename) {
    //Separo el nombre de la extension
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*)(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(filename);

    m.matches();

    String[] aux = {m.group(1), m.group(2)};

    return aux;
} 
}
```

Comment: Con `destino.renameTo(new  File(getValidName(destino.getAbsolutePath())));`lo que estas haciendo renombrar el fichero destino, es decir el de raiz. Aparte no deberias lanzar un throws IOException si no capturarla e intentar cerrar los flujos, si no se van a quedar abiertos y dara problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, problema solucionado, en cuanto a lo de IOException en cuanto haga la clase definitiva lo pondre como es debido. Gracias